# Help in understanding Urysohn metrization theorem

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

As a pure math lover i am reading Munkres Topology . I was reading Urysohn metrization theorem .

In the proof it is written : Let {$B_n$} be a countable basis for $X$.For each pair $n,m$ of indices for which $\bar B_n ⊂ B_m$ , apply the Urysohn lemma to choose a continuous function $g_{n,m}$ : $X → [0,1]$ such that $g_{n,m}(\bar B) = ${$1$}  and $g_{n,m}(X - B_m) = ${$0$} .

We can do above by Urosyhn Lemma but how can we claim that range of the function will be [0,1] ? It is possible that $g_{n,m}$ > 1 for $B_m - \bar B_n$

[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu3mk.png)

Comment: What is the statement of Urysohn's  Lemma you have seen?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Every regular space X with a countable basis is metrizable .

Comment: In the proofs of Urysohn's Lemma that I have seen in many texts the function constructed takes values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy I have uploaded the screenshot of the page . I did not got 6th point from bottom .How can we claim will be $[0,1]$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation of the Urysohn lemma in Munkres (2nd edition page 207, §33 ,Thm **33.1**) is

> Let $X$ be a normal space; let $A$,$B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X$. Let $[a,b]$ be a closed interval of the real line. Then there exists a continuous map $$f: X \to [a,b]$$ such that $f(x)=a$ for every $a \in A$ and $f(x)=b$ for every $x \in B$.

Apply this to the closed sets $A=\overline{B_n}$ and $B=X - B_m$ and choose $a=0,b=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $g_{nm}$ takes values in $[0,1]$ is part of the proof of Urysohn's Lemma. But even if you don't have this fact ready you can always replace $g_{nm}$ by $\max \{0, \min \{g_{nm},1\}\}$ to make sure that the range is contained in $[0,1]$.